# Make Text change color in the As3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to make a black rectangle (called R_1) and a white text (a textfield  called T_1) on it. After that, the rectangle R_1 should slowly reduces height and also the (T_1) change from white to black.

This is the example
http://postimg.org/image/6tuswaugf/
[image]

Comment: Is there anything you tried? Can you share it? As you are new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To do that, you can use masking like it's explained [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0b.html). So try to write something and if you have always the problem, we are here to help you.

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done with blending modes. I don't know how much you already know since you didnt show any code effort but you can try this below and ask or Google about any questions :

You must use a [blending mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html) called `INVERT`. Blending Modes only apply to MovieClips and Bitmaps. So make sure your items (text, rectangle etc) are inside MovieClip containers (using `addchild`).

You need three containers here. One for background canvas (white), one for text (black colour) and one more container for the resizing rectangle.

1) Make a new MovieClip to be Canvas. It shall be the white background (so maybe add a white rectangle shape in there. Here the green box just helps to see where the white Canvas area is).
[image]

2) Make a new MovieClip to be Text Holder. This contains a text with black font colour. So final appearance should be black text on white background.
[image]

3) Make a new MovieClip to be Rectangle. This has a black filled rectangle of same width & height as Canvas. Give this MovieClip a blending mode of `INVERT`. To do in code use `instanceName.blendMode = BlendMode.INVERT;` replace **instanceName** with your own instance name for the black rectangle MovieClip 
[image]

4) Testing with new smaller size rectangle. 
[image]

This works because we have a black rectangle on a layer above the background and text layers. So by giving the highest rectangle an `INVERT` mode it means every pixel colour below its area must be reverse of itself.